# how to make tabulations including weigths for surveys in R?

Tags: r

I would like to be able to make a tabulated report showing the confidence intervals of a survey using the `survey` or `questionr` libraries, does anyone know how to do them?

```
t = svydesign(id = ~record, strata = ~stratum, as.fpc = ~psu, data = totalSurv, weight = ~weight) 
res = svymean(~Soledad + Suicidio + Preocupacion + Amigos, t, deff = T, na.rm = T)
confint(res)
```

```
                  2.5 %     97.5 %
Loneliness    0.16105608 0.17405596
```

This is an example of what I need to report
[image: This is an example of what I need to report]

Comment: Could you provide the sample of data - use dput function.  I understand you want to do
svymean(FACTOR(variable with M13.sui and others)~Soledad+Suicidio+Preocupacion+Amigos,t,deff=T, na.rm=T). Then use package like rtables (github) to make a nice table.

Comment: I use a survey as data sample from students (men & women) with 13, 14 and 15 yo.
 I need to do the IC 95% with confint, but a cross table combinating Gender vs Age for all ages: 13, 14 and 15 yo for Man and Woman, so it'll be 6 combinations.

Comment: You could use interaction(var1,var2)  before and use it like this_new_var ~

Comment: It gave me this error when I put interaction. is this OK?

> th13=svydesign(id = ~record, strata = ~stratum, as.fpc = ~psu, data = H13, weight = ~weight) 
>resh13=svymean(~interaction(~Genero,Edad)~Soledad+Suicidio+Preocupacion+Amigos,th13,deff=T, na.rm=T)
Error in model.frame.default(x, design$variables, na.action = na.pass) : 
  objeto no es una matriz